# ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-30' pid:42 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'

Tags: deployment

I have error like that. Deploy Logs  in railway application. Thus is from deploy logs of railway. If you want I can share other things. I have error like that. Deploy Logs  in railway application. Thus is from deploy logs of railway. If you want I can share other things.
I have error like that. Deploy Logs  in railway application. Thus is from deploy logs of railway. If you want I can share other things.
I have error like that. Deploy Logs  in railway application. Thus is from deploy logs of railway. If you want I can share other things.

```
User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0
warnings.warn(SecurityWarning(ROOT_DISCOURAGED.format(

\-------------- celery@railway v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
\--- \*\*\*\*\* -----
\-- \*\*\*\*\*\*\* ---- Linux-4.19.0-22-cloud-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5 2023-04-17 08:23:15

- \*\*\* --- \* ---
- \*\* ---------- \[config\]
- \*\* ---------- .\> app:         Instagram:0x7f543f2c43d0
- \*\* ---------- .\> transport:   amqps://cxcarasm:\*\*@armadillo.rmq.cloudamqp.com:5671/cxcarasm
- \*\* ---------- .\> results:     disabled://
- \*\*\* --- \* --- .\> concurrency: 32 (prefork)
  \-- \*\*\*\*\*\*\* ---- .\> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
  \--- \*\*\*\*\* -----
  \-------------- \[queues\]
  .\> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery

\[tasks\]
. users.tasks.update_instagram_stats
\[2023-04-17 08:23:28,093: INFO/MainProcess\] Connected to amqps://cxcarasm:**@armadillo.rmq.cloudamqp.com:5671/cxcarasm
\[2023-04-17 08:23:29,212: INFO/MainProcess\] mingle: searching for neighbors
\[2023-04-17 08:23:32,781: INFO/MainProcess\] mingle: all alone
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,175: INFO/MainProcess\] celery@railway ready.
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,176: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-30' pid:42 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,186: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-29' pid:41 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,197: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-28' pid:40 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,207: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-27' pid:39 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,218: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-26' pid:38 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,228: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-25' pid:37 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,239: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-24' pid:36 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,249: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-23' pid:35 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,260: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-22' pid:34 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,270: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-21' pid:33 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,281: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-20' pid:32 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,291: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-19' pid:31 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,301: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-18' pid:30 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,312: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-17' pid:29 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,322: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-16' pid:28 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,333: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-15' pid:27 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,343: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-13' pid:25 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,354: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-12' pid:24 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,364: ERROR/MainProcess\] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-2' pid:14 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
\[2023-04-17 08:23:35,571: CRITICAL/MainProcess\] Unrecoverable error: WorkerLostError('Could not start worker processes')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
self.blueprint.start(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
step.start(parent)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 365, in start
return self.obj.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 332, in start
blueprint.start(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
step.start(parent)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 628, in start
c.loop(\*c.loop_args())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 71, in asynloop
raise WorkerLostError('Could not start worker processes')
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Could not start worker processes
celery beat v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus) is starting.
fffffffffffffffffff
\_\_    -    ... \_\_   -        \_
LocalTime -\> 2023-04-17 08:23:42
Configuration -\>
. broker -\> amqps://cxcarasm:**@armadillo.rmq.cloudamqp.com:5671/cxcarasm
. loader -\> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
. scheduler -\> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
. db -\> celerybeat-schedule
. logfile -\> \[stderr\]@%INFO
. maxinterval -\> 5.00 minutes (300s)
\[2023-04-17 08:23:42,480: INFO/MainProcess\] beat: Starting...
\[2023-04-17 08:23:43,404: INFO/MainProcess\] Scheduler: Sending due task update_instagram_stats (users.tasks.update_instagram_stats)
\[2023-04-17 08:26:42,702: INFO/MainProcess\] Scheduler: Sending due task update_instagram_stats (users.tasks.update_instagram_stats)

type here
```